# Add zeros at the begining of a 32 -bit binary number.

Tags: java

I have a program that transforms decimal number into a binary number.
I want the binary representation to have 32 digits, so I often need to add 0 at the beginning of the binary representation. How can I achieve it?

Example:

```
 decimal: 
   9999999
 binary:
   00000000  01001100  01001011  00111111
```

This is the code I already have:
Code:

```
class Binaer    {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        long a = scanner.nextLong();

        while ( a != 0) {
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(a));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not in English

Comment: just remove the `while` loop and it should work as expected.

Comment: @assylias This code doesn't compile, you cannot call `toBinaryString ` with a `long` as argument.

Comment: Pad the string with 0's...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; I hope your question has been answered. You should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) whichever answer answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

Easy, simply use `String.format`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final int i = 7;
    final String s = String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0');
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The first bit - `String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(i))` - formats the `int` as a binary `String` which is padded from the start to 32 characters. The second bit  - `replace(' ', '0')` -  replaces the leading spaces with zeros.

Comment: Why are `i` and `s` final?

Comment: @Steve because they do not need to be variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format` or a `StringBuilder` :

```
java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
int a = scanner.nextInt();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(a); i++)
    sb.append('0');
sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(a));
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you use Integer.toBinaryString(a), then a must be an Integer. Then, you can pad the received String using String.format:

```
number = Integer.toBinaryString(a);
paddedNumber = String.format("%32s", number).replace(' ', 0);
```

format will ensure paddedNumber has 32 signs by adding spaces at the beginning, if necessary. Then replace will replace spaces with '0' signs.